# Models association: where to put the foreign_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, model-associations

I`m working on a project that controls the equipment lendings to users.

It displays the lending view that renders a form where user can choose the equipment that he/she wants through a select box.If the equipment is not available in select box, user have to register the equipment then it will appear in that select box in lending view's form.

Model Association:

Lending   has_many Equipment

Equipment belongs_to Lending

The doubt is:
If Equipment belongs_to Lending then I must  put the lending_id in Equipment.

But if user access the new equipment view and try to register a new equipment it will
miss the lending_id.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please give more information on your models, specifically, what does a "lending" item represent? Also: a brand new item is not lent to anyone, yes?

Comment: let`s say someone wants to borrow a 'hp laptop', he will access the Lending form and select the hp laptop in the select box and there are more informations like user's name, equipment's brand, equipment's category (I prefer to simplify the question because the problem is in the association above) then he just register the lending.A new equipment is not lent to anyone.

Comment: I think you may have your roles reversed: a piece of equipment may be lent many times, but each "lending" is only one event. Given this, both equipment_id and user_id belongs on lending, and lending becomes a many-to-many relationship between equipment and users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is what you really want is for lending to be a many-to-many mapping of users to equipments.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lendings
    has_many :equipments, :through => :lendings

    # etc
end

class Equipment < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :lendings
    has_many :users, :through => :lendings

    # etc
end

class Lending < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :equipment

    # etc
end
```

You can write methods to give the "current" user for an equipment via the latest active lending, and vice-versa, plus you have a convenient history of all lendings of an item of equipment.